# Access GitHub Actions secrets from common repository

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I have 20 github repositories and implementing github actions. As we have 20 repos, I am thinking to move common code and secrets to one common repository and invoke them from main repos.
we are successful with putting the common code in common repository but NOT sure how to invoke the secrets from main repos. we are facing issue while invoking the common repo secrets.             Any suggestion s ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create an organization, and place the 20 repositories in it? You can share secrets from the organization to all the organization repositories.

Comment: Agree with @GuiFalourd - you don't want to put secrets in a repo